# How can I get two graphs side by side in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot

objects = [3598.827493, 3597.836761, 3597.818885, 3597.801053, 3597.783277]

x = np.arange(len(objects))

plt.subplot(1,2,2)

b = [5539.831326,5931.472022,5500.746584,5970.586012,5461.717599]

plt.plot(objects,b,objects,b,'g^')

plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.xlabel('Send Time')
plt.ylabel('Distance Features')
plt.title('Random Position Attack')



plt.subplot(1,2,1)


plt.plot(objects,b,objects,b,'g')

plt.grid(axis='y')

plt.xlabel('Send Time')
plt.ylabel('Distance Features')
plt.title('Random Position Attack')

plt.savefig('distance.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see getting overlap. But I need them to be perfect independent graphs side by side, and all axis values need to be clear as well. Also, I would like to have the control of the size of the graph.

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))` for the `xaxis` issue and `plt.tight_layout` for the overlapping issue.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work any better for you

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 3))

ax1.plot(objects, b, objects, b,'g^')

ax1.grid(axis='y')
ax1.set_xlabel('Send Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Distance Features')
ax1.set_title('Random Position Attack')
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45);

ax2.plot(objects,b,objects,b,'g')

ax2.grid(axis='y')
ax2.set_xlabel('Send Time')
ax2.set_ylabel('Distance Features')
ax2.set_title('Random Position Attack')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice way to do thanks a lot, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the overlap by simply adding `plt.tight_layout()` at the end like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot

objects = [3598.827493, 3597.836761, 3597.818885, 3597.801053, 3597.783277]

x = np.arange(len(objects))

plt.subplot(1,2,2)

b = [5539.831326,5931.472022,5500.746584,5970.586012,5461.717599]

plt.plot(objects,b,objects,b,'g^')

plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.xlabel('Send Time')
plt.ylabel('Distance Features')
plt.title('Random Position Attack')



plt.subplot(1,2,1)


plt.plot(objects,b,objects,b,'g')

plt.grid(axis='y')

plt.xlabel('Send Time')
plt.ylabel('Distance Features')
plt.title('Random Position Attack')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('distance.png')
plt.show()
```

To make sure the x axis labels don't overlap, you can simply increase the figure size like so:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
```

Or you can simply rotate the x-axis labels a little bit to get it showing like so:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support!